# Sortable - Excluded items still affect index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a *sortable* set up like this:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    items: '> *:not(.nosort)',
    axis: 'y',

    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var index = ui.item.index();
        // do something with the index
    }
});
```

I want to ignore elements with the `nosort` class from the sortable.

This works good; however, the index I get seems to include all elements in the sortable, not only those that can be sorted, so it can't really be used for what I need.

Is there any easy way to avoid this?

---

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/Yy9hW/) of an example sortable.

*(note: subtracting 1 from the index is not an option, because the number and position of excluded elements can vary)*

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a collection of `.sortable` children and then find the index, using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), based on that...

You can do that by making the following changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
        items: '> *:not(.nosort)',
        axis: 'y',

        stop: function (event, ui) {

            // obtain index of the moved item
            var index = $(this).children(':not(.nosort)').index(ui.item);

            $('#index').text(index);

        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Yy9hW/3/

Comment: @MightyPork made changes